# Speeding up slow nested loops through rows in dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

cluster_name size is 101,878

maxpaths size is 1,508,931

Dataframe looks like this

```
| cluster_name | maxpath             | chrom_pos          |
|--------------+---------------------+--------------------|
| cluster_1007 | 5_G,6_C,7_A,8_A,9_T | chr11:611117-799999|
| cluster_1007 | 5_G,6_C,7_A,8_A,9_T | chr11:611117-799999|
| cluster_1007 | 3_G,4_C,5_A,6_A,7_T | chr12:823492-102341|
```

What I'm trying to do is
for a given cluster I want to compare each maxpaths to other given maxpaths in
that cluster, I'm interested in the clusters where the maxpaths do not overlap
 and their annotations on the chromosome are also disjoint. For example 
"5_G,6_C,7_A,8_A,9_T" and "3_G,4_C,5_A,6_A,7_T" do not overlap and have
different annotations. One of the biggest pain points in my code is that I
compare each maxpath to all the other maxpaths in that cluster. Some clusters have over 1000 maxpaths so it slows down a lot. I tried to reduce the number of pairwise comparisons I do by returning the name of the cluster when it finds two maxpaths that fulfill the criteria. I've tried moving certain parts of the code into numpy arrays but it's still extremely slow. 
My code looks like this. Does anyone have any ideas that could help?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def find_cluster(cluster, maxpaths):
    """
   returns clusters with disjoint maxpaths annotated
   to different genomes or annotated on the same
   genome min of 10kb apart
    """
    for idx, item in enumerate(maxpaths):
        unique = set(item.split(','))
        for j in range(idx+1, len(maxpaths)):
            compare = set(maxpaths[j].split(','))
            chrom_string1 = subset_df[
                subset_df['maxpath'] == item]['chrom_pos'].values[0]
            chrom_string2 = subset_df[
                subset_df['maxpath'] == maxpaths[j]]['chrom_pos'].values[0]

            chrom1 = chrom_string1.split(':')[0]
            chrom_end1 = int(chrom_string1.split('-')[1])

            chrom2 = chrom_string2.split(':')[0]
            chrom_end2 = int(chrom_string2.split('-')[1])
            if len(unique.intersection(compare)) == 0:
                if chrom1 != chrom2:
                    return(cluster)
                elif chrom1 == chrom2:
                    if abs(chrom_end1 - chrom_end2) > 10000:
                        return(cluster)

file_number = input.df_subset.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]
df = pd.read_csv(input.df_subset)
cluster_names = df['cluster_name'].unique()
disjoint_clusters = []
for i in cluster_names:
    subset_df = df[df['cluster_name'] ==i]
    maxpaths_array = subset_df['maxpath'].as_matrix()
    cluster = find_cluster(i,maxpaths_array)
    disjoint_clusters.append(cluster)
    disjoint_maxpaths = pd.DataFrame({"clusters_with_disjoint_maxpaths":disjoint_clusters})
    disjoint_maxpaths.to_csv(os.path.abspath('results/disjoint_maxpath_clusters_{}.csv'.format(file_number)),index=False)
```

Comment: Your big-o (worst case) complexity is O3, (outer + func outer + func inner). I would look at ways you can optimize (reduce) the number of iterations you must perform.

Answer (score 1):

After incorporating some of the suggested ideas this is what I came up with. I lost readability but what I needed was performance. Whole run took about 2 hours to finish on my main computer.

```
def find_cluster(cluster_name, dataframe):
    """
   returns clusters with disjoint maxpaths annotated
   to different genomes or annotated on the same
   genome min of 10kb apart
    """
    cluster = cluster_name
    df = dataframe
    maxpaths = [set(item) for item in [_.split(',') for _ in df['maxpath'].as_matrix()]]
    chrom_string = df['chrom_pos'].as_matrix()
    chrom = [_.split(':')[0] for _ in df['chrom_pos'].as_matrix()]
    chrom_end = [int(_.split('-')[1]) for _ in df['chrom_pos'].as_matrix()]
    for idx,item in enumerate(maxpaths):
        for j in range(idx+1, len(maxpaths)):
            if item.isdisjoint(maxpaths[j]):
                if chrom[idx] != chrom[j]:
                    return(cluster)
                elif chrom[idx] == chrom[j]:
                    if abs(chrom_end[idx] - chrom_end[j]) > 10000:
                        return(cluster)

def df_to_dict(dataframe):
    """ 
    Create dict with cluster as key and
    subset of dataframe at cluster as value
    """
    df = dataframe
    unique_clusters = df['cluster_name'].unique()
    sub_dfs = []
    for i in unique_clusters:
        sub_dfs.append(df[df['cluster_name'] == i])
    return(dict(zip(unique_clusters, sub_dfs)))

def get_clusters(dataframe):
    """
    return disjoint clusters
    """
    df = pd.read_csv(dataframe, index_col=False)
    df_dict = df_to_dict(df)
    disjoint = [find_cluster(k,v) for k,v in df_dict.items() if find_cluster(k,v)]
    return(disjoint)


def test_new():
    cluster = ["cluster_689"]
    disjoint_cluster = []
    for i in cluster:
        found = find_cluster(i, subset_df)
        disjoint_cluster.append(found)
    return(disjoint_cluster)

def test_old():
    cluster = ["cluster_689"]
    disjoint_cluster = []
    for i in cluster:
        maxpaths_array = subset_df['maxpath'].as_matrix()
        found = old_find_cluster(i,maxpaths_array)
        disjoint_cluster.append(found)
    return(disjoint_cluster)

new = %timeit for x in range(3): test_new()
old = %timeit for x in range(3): test_old()
```

yields

New find_cluster
247 µs ± 5.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Old find_cluster
138 ms ± 587 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

The speed up when looking for disjoint max paths is immense. I wasn't able to calculate the time for the whole script because the last few large clusters never finished running after over 24 hours. This was after splitting up the data frame into 100 smaller dataframes as well. But i'm sure overall the script became faster outside of the find_clusters function. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

There is some scope for improvement. Basically your code is pythonic, but if performance loss (over readability gain) is unacceptable, you should look at least somewhat deeper, into things such as repeated iterations that you do, and convenience functions which take iterables as inputs and again/repeatedly iterate over (possibly the same) data.

- Avoid repeating iterations.
  You are repeating iterations (such as with `df['cluster_name'].unique()` and again iterating all rows in for loop, then again subsetting array multiple times at `df[df['cluster_name'] ==i]` which is conditional execution, that gets repeated a lot of times for same values). Instead you can just iterate over the whole data once, keep a `dict` like mapping for cluster (eg. cluster name mapped to a list of sets of `max_path`s), check if the `max_path`s for current cluster name entry are already present in that dictionary's corresponding entry, and accumulate clusters passing your conditions. This also helps repeated creations of exactly same `set`s that's happening with your current code.
- Another example of repeated heavy computation:

  `cluster_names = df['cluster_name'].unique()
  disjoint_clusters = []
  for i in cluster_names:
      subset_df = df[df['cluster_name'] ==i]`

  You can at least keep (cache) and reuse subsets instead of re-computing.
- Do not compute unnecessary expressions, and look for items breaking your conditions. Eg. `len(unique.intersection(compare)) == 0` is slower than `unique.isdisjoint(compare)` because the latter one short-circuits and your data seem to have that case more frequently. Basically you don't need that intersection, you just need to check if they're disjoint.
- Here, again the same sets are being constructed (which themselves involve iterations over input iterables) repeatedly, with the `dict` approach above, those repetitions are avoided.

There is one shortcoming with the suggested approach thought, it may consume more memory but I guess that shouldn't be a troublesome difference.

Also I assume you need all clusters passing your conditions, and not stop at just 2. In that case it can be made even faster.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will take your advice as I work on improving the code. I think I have a idea of how it can be improved now.